# MVC3 Transactions Counters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to count the number of transactions which retrieves some reports from database (SQL Server). I am using EF4.1 for database interactions and MVC3 for client.

Could anyone suggest best way to do and place (in controller or in reposity service etc).

I want to restrict the user to maximum 100 transactions per hour. After this limit I would lock the user and log-out as well. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to count the number of queries the user does, or the number of writes to the DB?

Comment: anyone of these. I am actualy retrieving information from mainframe and putting it into SQL database each time user request something. So now i want to restrict user to check maximum 100 reports from mainframe (thus by SQL) per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly business logic, so the "action" (decision) needs to be in your business logic layer.

In the DB, keep a table with consumed quota per day and update that table every time the user performs a counted action (such as retrieving a particular report or writing to the database). That is, your business logic contains instructions to update the consumed quota counter per such operation.

Add validation logic in your business layer that reads the consumed quota for the user, and only validate (i.e., allow) if the daily quota for that user has not been reached.

Clean up the quota every day if necessary, but you may want to keep it for accounting purposes.

Comment: well this quota is : 100 per user per hour. So every time I go to SQL to add report, I need to update the counter as well as time at which that transaction is made. Then to check time for last 100 transactions? Am I going good?? :)

Comment: It depends on how you define "per hour". Is it exactly between 1 and 2, then again between 2 and 3, or is it 100 reports per 60 minutes? Then simply retrieve the number of consumed items in the last 60 minutes (so where the timestamp is less than 60 minutes old). If the number is less than 100, you can allow the transaction to pass. When the transaction passes (in the business logic), it logs the transaciton in that table.

Comment: it is 100 reports per 60 mins. So I need to add new table to log report-id and date-time for each transanction per user. I am updating the report table after user makes new transaction so can't use count of reports..

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look in to a `ActionFilterAttribute` that can be applied globally (across all controllers) in the `MvcApplication` class, `RegisterGlobalFilters` method. Something like:

```
public class FilterTrafficAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Log and track visitor count for the hour here, and decide if they
        // should proceed on or not.
        // You can also change the ActionResult of the request by altering the
        // filterContext.Result.
    }
}
```

Then in the `MvcApplication`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandlerErrorAttribute());

    // add this line:
    filters.Add(new FilterTrafficAttribute());
}
```

Then you're insuring it's applied to all calls, and have a lot of handling ability. There are other overrides you may be interested in with [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx)

Comment: I am also a big fan of ActionFilters. But I cant use it here seems like. I would try to log the time at a new table during retrieval of report.